# Mixing Knockout foreach with static elements in a Bootstrap button group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm trying to mix a `foreach` with static elements in a Bootstrap btn-group, because I would like some of the buttons to be placeholders for future options. So I set it up like this:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <span data-bind="foreach: router.visibleRoutes">
        <a data-bind="css: { active: isActive }, attr: { href: hash }, text: name" href="#" class="btn btn-info"></a>
    </span>
    <div class="btn btn-info">Future Option</div>
    <div class="btn btn-info">Future Option</div>
</div>
```

However, this causes the buttons produced with the `foreach` to have rounded corners on all sides so that they don't sit "flush" the way you would expect in a `btn-group`. The `span` interrupts the normal button group styling. I also tried containerless composition:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <!-- ko foreach: router.visibleRoutes -->
        <a data-bind="css: { active: isActive }, attr: { href: hash }, text: name" href="#" class="btn btn-info"></a>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <div class="btn btn-info">Future Option</div>
    <div class="btn btn-info">Future Option</div>
</div>
```

but it results in the same `span` tag when rendered, so the effect is the same. If I put the `foreach` on the `btn-group` div, that would cause the static elements to repeat for each `router.visibleRoutes`, which is unacceptable. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your second approach works.  Could it be a browser cache issue?

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ptw8a/

```
<!-- ko foreach: visibleRoutes -->
    <a data-bind="css: { active: isActive }, attr: { href: hash }, text: name" href="#" class="btn btn-info"></a>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I can't find any reasons why your second approach would generate a span object.